# Semantic HTML markup for FAQs

Tags: html, semantics, markup

I want to build a questions and answers page.

It is not a list, it is not tabular data and I am not sure if or how I should use `<dl><dt><dd>`.

What html elements should be used to construct an FAQ to ensure semantic correctness and accessability?

Comment: One of the frustrating things about semantics is that sometimes there isn't a right or wrong answer. `<dl>` is appropriate (thanks to its [new meaning in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/)), headers and paragraphs work well too, and you could also use [`<details>`/`<summary>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/) to make collapsing FAQs if you have way too many questions and want to keep it tidy.

Comment: I think it would be valuable to re-open this question. Semantic HTML/A11y questions often seem opinion-based because they're complex and can have multiple correct answers, but this doesn't mean that the answers aren't useful. It's especially important to have considered answers around these issues because there *is* so little authoritative information around a11y questions out there.

This particular question addresses a very valid query - how to build a FAQ with semantic HTML to ensure a11y - for which devs don't necessarily have other places to find clear answers.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I always use <dl> for FAQs.  Typically making the <dt> an anchor for the index of questions to link.

**edit...**

I should mention, this is my interpretation of the most semantic approach.  As I see it, this is exactly the sort of thing <dl> is meant to mark up.

As for CSS, it's really subjective.  I do typical heading-ish styles for the <dt>, with a high font-weight, maybe slightly higher font-size, and maybe greater letter/word spacing.

Whatever integrates well with the rest of your visuals on the site and makes the relationship between the question and answer immediately obvious....

Answer (score 20):

I'd go with the simplest model; each question is a heading, with answers in paragraph tags. Clear, logical and semantically sane, I think.

The reason I wouldn't use the definition list tags mentioned is that I don't think, from a pure semantic point of view, that questions and answers fit the mould of pure terms and definitions.

Comment: An article from 2007's 24ways addresses semantic use of DL. It manages to avoid this specific situation, but is still relevent.

http://24ways.org/2007/my-other-christmas-present-is-a-definition-list

Comment: Interesting read, and an interesting site; thanks for the link.

Comment: what's the worst that can happen (serious question) with using definition lists? does google get confused / do screen readers get confused? I realize it's not a perfect match but I don't see a better alternative

Comment: Definition lists now have a new role, thanks to HTML5: they're called 'description' lists instead, and can be used for any name/value combinations. http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/