# Is there a better way to semantically code up an FAQ in XHTML 1.0 Transitional?

Tags: xhtml, semantic-markup

The following code segment for an FAQ, which uses XHTML 1.0, will not validate successfully in the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

I’m inserting the Q&A into a definition list in order to maintain the question & answer relationship semantically. The problem is, the questions can be multiple paragraphs. And the `<dt>` tag, at least in XHTML 1.0, only allows for inline elements. So I can’t put a `<p>` tag in there without throwing an error in the W3C validator.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<dl>
    <dt>
        <p>This is a very long question.</p>
        <p>It has multiple paragraphs.</p>
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <p>This is the answer</p>
    </dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a semantically better way of coding this using XHMTL 1.0 Transitional?

For reference, the latest similar thread I can find on the topic is this is [What is the best way to semanticly structure a FAQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470194/what-is-the-best-way-to-semanticly-structure-a-faq). The thread was useful, however it does not cover multiple paragraphs in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `dl` element doesn’t seem to be appropriate.

XHTML 1.0 [uses](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#abstract) the element definitions from HTML 4.01, where the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) is defined to be a "definition list". A list of Q&As is probably not a *definition* list (unless, maybe, the term to be defined is just phrased as question, e.g., "What is the definition of foo?").

HTML5 re-defines the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element): it’s no longer a definition list, but an "association list", or "description list". It might be appropriate to use it for Q&As, and the [`dt` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element) can now also contain most of the flow content elements (which includes `p`). So this might be suitable if you want to use (X)HTML5. (The [example for `dt`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dt-element) even shows a FAQ.)

Possible alternatives, depending on the actual content and context:

- Just use `p` and rely on textual semantics, i.e., the "?" makes clear that it’s a question. You could also prefix them with "Question:" and "Answer:" (e.g., in `b`).
- Use a heading (`h1`-`h6`) for each Q&A. As they neither may contain `p` elements, you might have to use something like "Question 1" as heading content, and rely on the text again.

Comment: Thanks for response.
I actually switched to using headings with my more recent FAQ. And I’m using separate CSS classes to visually distinguish the Q&A on the presentation layer.
I wish there was a way to identify the relationship to user agents. But I guess this simply wasn’t available in XHTML 1.0. 
I wonder if WAI-ARIA can be used for this?
Thanks again.

Comment: w3.org  _Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, **questions and answers**, or any other groups of name-value data._